# Why DragAndDrop does only work with the last added Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi, drag, drop

I am struggeling with Drag and Drop in a react Component.
I want to drag and drop different buttons in my App.

Therefore I created a Hook like:

```
const [{isDragging}, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: 'button',
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  }))
```

Then later in the return construct, I use this as a ref:

```
{articleList.map((item, idx) => {
        return(
          <Accordion expanded={isElementExpanded(item.id)} onToggle={handleToggle2(item.id)} id={item.id} size="S">
            ...
                    {item.Blocks.map((block, index) => {
                      return(
...
                          <Button id={'button-'+index} ref={drag} ...></Button>...
```

The Problem is, that only one Button, the last added, is draggable. The others own an attribute with draggable = "false". It is strange because I render all Buttons with ref={drag}.

Where is my error?

thank,
Sven

Comment: There is only one `drag` ref but you're creating multiple Button elements, so only the last one gets assigned to the ref. This is covered in the React docs [here](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback)

Comment: Super, thanks. I did not found this info. Wonderful. But, now the question. It works in so far, I can set the attribute draggable to every button to true. But how can I connect the drag-Hook?

Comment: Is that your own `useDrag` hook or does it come from a library? Perhaps you instead want to create a new "DraggableButton" component, where inside of there you use the `useDrag()` hook and return your `<Button>`. Then rather than mapping to `Button` components, you would drag to `DrabbleButton` components.

Comment: Yes, it is my useDrag-Hook inside my Component.

Comment: Nick, you made my day! It works now, thank you so much!!! I will a little bit later publish my solution. Thank you.